# Stepper Value increases once for every 2 clicks

Tags: ios, uitableview, uistepper

I'm using a custom table view cell with a stepper and a label.
But when i check the value of the stepper it increases only once for every 2 presses.
What is the problem?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellData";
    ItemCell *cell = [self.myTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[ItemCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.stepper.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.countLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g",cell.stepper.value];
    NSLog(@"value = %g",cell.stepper.value);
    cell.itemLabel.text = [self.groceryItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (IBAction)valueChanged:(id)sender
{
    UIStepper *step = sender;
    NSIndexPath *index = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:step.tag inSection:0];
    NSArray *rowsToReload = [NSArray arrayWithObject:index];
    [self.myTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:rowsToReload withRowAnimation:NO];
}
```

Comment: If I use  [self.myTableView reloadData]; then it works fine.

Comment: You might consider using `%d` in place of `%g`.
`%d = 32bit-integer`
`%g = 64bit-double`

Comment: stepper.value is a double, so i used %g

Comment: So why not just use reloadData then?

Answer (score 0):

try to add this to your valueChanged Method:

```
[self.myTableView beginUpdates];
[self.myTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:rowsToReload withRowAnimation:NO];
[self.myTableView endUpdates];
```